# in WSO2 I can't store image in a property

Tags: wso2, apache-axis, wso2-enterprise-integrator, apache-synapse, ei

in WSO2 I try to make a call to given URLs to get png images in a pretty basic way. Then when I try to store/enrich I get the same error every time:

```
> [2021-07-02 16:38:38,357] ERROR {RelayUtils} - Error while building
> Passthrough stream org.apache.axiom.om.OMException:
> com.ctc.wstx.exc.WstxIOException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0x89 (at
> char #1, byte #-1)    at
> org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.next(StAXOMBuilder.java:296)
>   at
> org.apache.axiom.om.impl.llom.OMDocumentImpl.getOMDocumentElement(OMDocumentImpl.java:109)
>   at
> org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:570)
>   at
> org.apache.axiom.om.impl.builder.StAXOMBuilder.getDocumentElement(StAXOMBuilder.java:566)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.DeferredMessageBuilder.getDocument(DeferredMessageBuilder.java:165)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:169)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.util.RelayUtils.buildMessage(RelayUtils.java:122)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.buildMessage(AbstractListMediator.java:152)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:95)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.eip.splitter.IterateMediator.mediate(IterateMediator.java:341)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:267)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.mediateFromContinuationStateStack(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:809)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:309)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.handleMessage(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:583)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseCallbackReceiver.receive(SynapseCallbackReceiver.java:197)
>   at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
>   at
> org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ClientWorker.run(ClientWorker.java:285)
>   at
> org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
>   at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
>   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

what I try is basically this

```
<call>
                            <endpoint>
                                <http method="get" uri-template="{uri.var.imageURL}">
                                    <suspendOnFailure>
                                        <initialDuration>-1</initialDuration>
                                        <progressionFactor>1</progressionFactor>
                                    </suspendOnFailure>
                                    <markForSuspension>
                                        <retriesBeforeSuspension>0</retriesBeforeSuspension>
                                    </markForSuspension>
                                </http>
                            </endpoint>
                        </call>
                        <log level="full"/>
```

I know the URL is valid and uri.var.imageURL contains it. If I don't add log/enrich/payload mediators, I don't get any errors

I added these two rows to axis2.xml in their respective sections but nothing changed

```
<messageFormatter contentType="image/png" 
                  class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.ExpandingMessageFormatter"/>


<messageBuilder contentType="image/png" 
                class="org.wso2.carbon.relay.BinaryRelayBuilder"/>
```

Comment: Can you share which API Manager version you are using? And, also share what sort of  `Content-Type` is received from the Backend in the Headers?

Comment: @Athiththan content-type is image/png and I'm running it in integration studio 7.2.0 locally

Comment: What exactly do you want to log? I feel like the level="full" causes issues here as it tries to parse the image as xml.

Comment: @Novren yeah it is the last thing I tried in desperation so I just copy/pasted that :D but mainly I need it to assigned in a variable to encode in base64. I tried enrich mediator too but the result is the same.

Comment: Our team has been in this position a few times before with image situations on EI. Always causes annoying problems. We opted to download the images to disc via a custom mediator and then to retrieve it again with the fileConnector in application/octet-stream form and then send it where-ever needed. Hopefully someone else has a good solution sorry, Goodluck!

Comment: The above error is produced when the EI is not able to build the message properly. If the `MessageBuilder` and `MessageFormatter` not chosen correctly according to the `Content-Type` that is received, then this behavior can be observed. Just to confirm, if you have a standalone EI server, can you make the same changes there and see how that behaves? If you are using latest versions of EI, you have to make the changes in the `deployment.toml` and not directly in the `axis2.xml`.